# Measure Vcc on ATtiny13a?

Tags: attiny, code-review, adc, voltage

I am trying to figure out if I can measure the Vcc of attiny13a, but the code I use for arduino's and attiny85 does not work. [This is where I got the code from.](https://provideyourown.com/2012/secret-arduino-voltmeter-measure-battery-voltage/) I know that it works by using the 1.1v reference and the ADC, and in the attiny13a datasheet it says that it has these, but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code you linked to measures the 1.1 V internal reference using
Vcc as a reference. The ATtiny13A cannot do that. It does have a 1.1 V
internal reference, but it can only use it as a reference for the ADC,
not as a measured channel.

What you can do, if you don't mind adding extra hardware, is divide Vcc
with some resistors in order to get a voltage proportional to Vcc but
lower than 1.1 V. Then use the 1.1 V reference to measure that
voltage. In other words, measure a scaled-down Vcc against the
1.1 V reference instead of measuring the 1.1 V reference
against Vcc. The datasheet should help you with the details.

Comment: I tried this and it worked! I don't understand to much about the bit settings on the datasheet but with the help of a tutorial I got it to work Thankyou